# A Column to count number of distinct values in column X based on column Y?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

In SSMS 2016, I have a select statement with various joins which gives me the following data:

```
| box_barcode | order_number | order_shipment_id | item     | qty |
|-------------|--------------|-------------------|----------|-----|
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-S | 1   |
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-M | 2   |
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-L | 2   |
|  3330000005 | 0000108      | FP002             | shorts-S | 2   |
|  3330000005 | 0000108      | FP002             | shorts-M | 1   |
|  3330000005 | 0000120      | FP002             | shorts-S | 1   |
|  3330000010 | 0000120      | FP003             | shirts-M | 2   |
|  3330000010 | 0000120      | FP003             | shirts-L | 2   |
|  3330000010 | 0000121      | FP003             | shirts-S | 3   |
|  3330000010 | 0000121      | FP003             | shirts-M | 3   |
|  3330000010 | 0000122      | FP003             | shirts-S | 2   |
```

I'd like to add a column to count the number of distinct order_numbers for each box_barcode, for the desired result:

```
| box_barcode | order_number | order_shipment_id | item     | qty | count |
|-------------|--------------|-------------------|----------|-----|-------|
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-S | 1   | 1
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-M | 2   | 1
|  3330000001 | 0000105      | FP001             | tshirt-L | 2   | 1
|  3330000005 | 0000108      | FP002             | shorts-S | 2   | 2
|  3330000005 | 0000108      | FP002             | shorts-M | 1   | 2
|  3330000005 | 0000120      | FP002             | shorts-S | 1   | 2
|  3330000010 | 0000120      | FP003             | shirts-M | 2   | 3
|  3330000010 | 0000120      | FP003             | shirts-L | 2   | 3
|  3330000010 | 0000121      | FP003             | shirts-S | 3   | 3
|  3330000010 | 0000121      | FP003             | shirts-M | 3   | 3
|  3330000010 | 0000122      | FP003             | shirts-S | 2   | 3
```

I'm struggling to find out how best to achieve this. I know of count(distinct..), but would I have to put my current query into a subquery for the count to go against the results of that query first?

Comment: yes..get the counts for each box_barcode and join it with the table. you could've done it with a `count` window function..but it doesn't support `distinct`.

Comment: I'd use a Common Table Expression to calculate the number of distinct order numbers per box_barcode, then JOIN your CTE to your query and display that value as a parameter in the SELECT statement.  If you make your whole query with a bunch of joins into a View, then it'll look a little neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option with `dense_rank` and `max`.

```
select t.*,
       max(rnk) over(partition by box_barcode) as distinct_count
from (select t.*,
      dense_rank() over(partition by box_barcode order by order_numbers) as rnk
      from t
     ) t
```

The highest ranked row (using dense_rank) will be the distinct number of order numbers per box_barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  But it is easy enough to emulate:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by box_barcode) as distinct_count
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by box_barcode, order_numbers order by box_barcode) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: you must have forgot the `over` clause in `sum`.